# Segmentation Fault 11 at Archiving Obj C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an app, and at the moment to Archiving it, i get the Segmentation Fault 11 on X Code (I'm using xcode 7).

Already tried restart xcode, eliminate the only dependency (The cocoapod of google maps). The rare thing is that in te Simulator and in an iPad, the app compiles and runs normally, only when i try to Archive it, at the Linking step, it crashes.

This is the output of the error.

```
Ld /Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spapp.build/Release-iphoneos/spapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/spapp normal arm64
cd /Users/maxclowreed/Documents/OnlyWebStudio/spapp
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -L/Users/maxclowreed/Documents/OnlyWebStudio/spapp/build/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/maxclowreed/Documents/OnlyWebStudio/spapp/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks -filelist /Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spapp.build/Release-iphoneos/spapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/spapp.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreText -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework ImageIO -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spapp.build/Release-iphoneos/spapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/spapp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/maxclowreed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spapp-gmcplcaxmebxtjcahseviqjhmvwc/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/spapp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/spapp.build/Release-iphoneos/spapp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/spapp
```

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/maxclowreed/Documents/OnlyWebStudio/spapp/build/Debug-iphoneos'
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No, i don't, another day it work normally, on certain days the error appear again.